# R script breaks when asked to update packages

Tags: r

I have a a script that I want to run, but first I want to load source() and a library() in R. R keeps asking me to update the package, which breaks my script. My script works without updating and works if I just wait for the sources to load and say n to updating and run everything afterwards. My question is how to automatically say no or stop R from asking?

Comment: It also says it cannot update all packages every time I say yes, so that isn't an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, it is good practice to work with the latest version of packages, since you typically won't be given any support when working with an outdated version.

First, see where R will install the packages by checking the list of libraries:

```
.libPaths()
```

Then check that you have permission to write to the libraries (this is OS-dependent).

Then update all your packages using

```
update.packages(ask = FALSE)
```

Once your packages are up to date, you won't be asked to updated them.